# Hostility in Germany

Tags: germany

I am an open-minded Indian student and I will be going to Germany to join the University of Bonn for my masters in Computer Science. I have a few queries that are plaguing me right now. Here they are:

1. Are Indians met with hostility? I mean for the fact that we are
   studying from the money of German taxpayers (which I personally
   respect and acknowledge), so will we be considered
   inferior/neglected etc.? I have read that people @ Bonn are direct
   and call a spade a spade, but how diverse will be its effect? Will I
   be able to survive it with my initial little to no German language
   knowledge?
2. What should I do to fit in Germany perfectly?

Comment: I was in that position once. It gets better with your language proficiency, don't allow them to speak English to you.  Also your street cred will take your academic performance into account. Study hard and excel...

Comment: I don't think the money thing is a concern. Racism might be (mostly outside the university I would think and not necessarily in Bonn but more in other parts of the country) and not speaking German makes many thing more difficult but fellow students won't resent you for being a foreign student *per se*.

Comment: Coincidentally, I just learnt that someone with Indian roots is running for mayor of Bonn for one of the major parties ([source](http://www.rundschau-online.de/bonn/ashok-sridharan-bonner-cdu-waehlt-ob-kandidaten,15185502,29125088.html)).

Answer (score 3):

There is a huge mentality difference between Germany and India. Those two cultures are on the opposite ends when it comes to directness, so it's quite possible you'll feel normal "German way of communication" as extremely hostile.

Please read on as much as possible between intercultural issues between Germany and India, there are plenty examples online to be found, since there are many Indians in Germany due to strong IT presence. Otherwise, you are up to many surprises.

Comment: Can you provide some links, or a search strategy?  My searches mostly turned up pieces on cultural relations between the countries, or general information for expats in Germany or India (mostly aimed at expatriated Americans or Europeans rather than Indians).

Comment: @Marko is missing the key terminology used, "High Context" and "Low Context". These are applied to a culture's communication style. In low context cultures like German countries, you can answer "yes" or "no" to a question, no matter who you are speaking with. Whereas in India (very high context) you must condition your answer based on the status of the person you are speaking with.

Comment: This is a very good introductory video which will have some applicability to an Indian in Germany - Even though it is an American and Chinese participants. https://www.futurelearn.com/courses/intercultural-communication/0/steps/11072

Comment: Tons more of educational stuff here: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=training+high+context+communication+versus+low+context+communication&client=firefox-b-ab&prmd=ivns&source=lnms&tbm=vid&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjt88i2saLOAhWDhRoKHSaaAQIQ_AUIBg